# Problemas con consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

Bueno, tengo una tabla, la cual esta relacionada con cuatro tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La anterior imagen es la tabla principal, y las llaves hacia estas otras tablas son gobe_id, alca_id, conse_id, asam_id.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la anterior tabla esta una de las 4 que esta relacionadas, en este caso la de gobe_id, la otras son casi iguales solo con un nombre de campo diferente.

El problema es, que cuando consulto todo en tabla usuarios, pues aparece todos los registros, por ejemplo en gobe_id aparece un numero, 1, 3, 4, etc, la cosa es que he tratado de que en vez de que me apezca un numero o id, me muestre el nombre, osea governor_candidate, es primera vez que me topo con esta necesidad y no se como hacer ese reemplazo.

Comment: Por favor cambia las imágenes por texto con ese contenido y compártenos también la consulta que estás lanzando y los resultados, todo en texto. No se entiendo del todo el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un `JOIN`.  Intenta con este query:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios JOIN governor ON usuarios.gobe_id = governor.id;
```

Comment: alanfcm entendio, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.